# Javascript: proportionally "scale" array of numbers to sum to a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have an array of numbers in javascript - for example:

```
[ 100, 100, 100, 100 ]
```

Given that the array must sum to a value - i'll use 100 as the example, I'm trying to create a function that would proportionally scale up or down this dataset resulting in each value equaling 25 - for example. If I run this function, then remove one of the values from the array resulting in an array like:

```
[25,25,25]
```

The function would return values of 33.3333- for each of the remaining entries so it still sums to exactly 100.

Additionally, if I were to iterate one of those values by 1, creating an array of:

```
[33.33333,33.33333,34.33333]
```

and a sum of 101, the function would need to reduce the other non-modified entries proportionally to result in a sum of exactly 100, which means I would need the capability to ,optionally, exclude a value from this calculation based on it's index within the array. I'm looking for something like this:

```
function ProportionallyScale(array,mustsumto,exclude = false) { 
//do math 
return array;
}
```

Comment: what is the result of the last array?

Comment: 101 - that example is related to the fact that I need to reduce the unmodified values to accommodate for the iteration of the value that was just modified. So the two instances of 33.33 would both need to be reduced by 0.5 (and the 34.33 untouched) to result in a sum of 100.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would approach this question:

- Find the total sum of all the values in the array
- Divide each value by the total sum
- Multiply each value by 100

This is clearly a homework question so I won't write the code for you, but for each of these things, you'll need a for() loop. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. It's actually related to a simple tool i'm building on my website, which needs to rescale a bunch of divs into a container totaling a height of 100% when a user adds or removes one - or increases the size of one +- 1%. Your approach would work for everything except when one value in the array is increased, and the remaining values need to be increased/decreased to sum to 100 (the part about excluding a value from the calculation). How do I go about that part?

Comment: Just use CSS for that. That's what it's for

Comment: This all needs to happen upon user input with dynamically created content - that's why I'm using JS. After I run the calculations in JS, I'm using jQuery to update the CSS with the new percentages.